# Convert string with Am/pm maker to date in Java

Tags: java, date, format

I want to convert string `"10/7/2015 6:31am"` to `Date` in java.
I tried follows code, but failed.

```
String value = "10/7/2015 6:31am";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy h:mma");
return sdf.parse(value);
```

What `SimpleDateFormat` should I use, please help me

actually, I made a function as follows in Utils.java:

```
public static Date getDateValueByFormat(String value,String format) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            return sdf.parse(value);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

called this function in others class as follows:

```
String value = "10/7/2015 6:31am";
Date datetime = Utils.getDateValueByFormat(value, "M/d/yyyy h:mma");
```

unfortunately, threw excption as follows:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10/7/2015 6:31am"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at com.sapmle.common.util.Utils.getDateValueByFormat(Utils.java:28)
```

anyone has idea?

PS: I used jdk is 1.7.0_79, has any problem for it?

Comment: How did it fail?  It seems to work for me

Comment: if that helps: I had to surround "sdf.parse()" with a try-catch block or else the IDE  won't accept it.

Comment: Well your question lacks clarity, you have posted a working code with unclear requirement.

Comment: What is your current locale? Does it work if you use a local like `java.util.Locale.ENGLISH`?

Comment: Try by passing the Locale like `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format,Locale.US);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom, prashant thakre,
Thank you very much!

I successed by your way:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format,Locale.US);
```